# Is this eigenvalue property true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does the following property hold for any matrix $A_n \in \mathbb R^{n x n}$?

The set of eigenvalues of $A_n - \mu I_n$ is $\{ \lambda_i(A)-\mu \}_{i=1}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by definition you have $Ax = \lambda x$ for the eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs, and thus  $(A - \mu I)x = Ax - \mu x = \lambda x - \mu x = (\lambda - \mu)x$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I could not see that.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a polynomial and we denote the set of eigenvalues of $A$ by $E_A$ then the spectral mapping property is valid:

$E_{p(A)}=p(E_A)$.

In your situation: $p(x)=x- \mu$